# Creating SQL Table with variable name from Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create and write a DataFrame to a SQL table using Python. The table should be named after a variable, specifically `table_name` (`table_name` will change as I run my code).  Below is the relevant part of my code to try to set this up:

```
con = sql.connect(r'/Users/linnk/Desktop/Results/Data.db')  # Creates database to write to
cur = con.cursor() 

...code...

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + table_name + ''' (Date, Morning1, Day1, Evening1, Night1, Morning3, Day3, Evening3, Night3)''')
```

Running this gives the error (for the last line):

```
OperationalError: near "-": syntax error
```

I've tried making several modifications to the last line of my code but get similar errors. Can anyone help me spot my mistake/make the necessary adjustments to my code? For information, table_name contains a string.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

From what I've read it seems to be better to make a string that is then passed to cur.execute():

```
   stringexecute='''\'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '''+ table_name +''' (Date, Morning1 real, Day1 real, Evening1 real, Night1 real, Morning3 real, Day3 real, Evening3 real, Night3 real)\''''
   cur.execute(stringexecute)
```

For information, stringexecute outputs:

```
stringexecute= 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GUTUR_400_F1-KIAGA-1 (Date, Morning1Ph real, Day1Ph real, Evening1Ph real, Night1Ph real, Morning3Ph real, Day3Ph real, Evening3Ph real, Night3Ph real)'
```

The code still doesn't work, however. It gives:

```
OperationalError: near "'CREATE TABLE ......'": syntax error
```

Any further help would be much appreciated. I've primarily looked at and (unsuccessfully) tried the methods from the following resources:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

**EDIT**

It turns out the following works, as long as the variable `table_name` does not contain '-' (and possibly other symbols):

```
 cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + " (Date, Morning1 real, Day1 real, Evening1 real, Night1 real, Morning3 real, Day3 real, Evening3 real, Night3 real)")
```

Comment: What happens if you hard code a table name?

Comment: That appears to work - this creates 'Table1' in the database:   
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1 (Date, Morning1, Day1, Evening1, Night1, Morning3, Day3, Evening3, Night3)''')

Comment: Based on your last update it seems the problem was only forbidden characters. Can you regex.sub those before executing the table creation step?

Comment: I simply used dataframe.replace() and replaced '-' with '_'

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tab} (Date, Morning1, Day1, Evening1, Night1, Morning3, Day3, Evening3, Night3)'
   .format(tab=table_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code:

```
def crear_tabla (name):
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE {tab}
  (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
  NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
  AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
  SALARY         REAL);'''.format(tab=name))
print ("Table created successfully")
cur.close()
conn.commit()
```